# Show my own application in share dialog in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I am an Android Developer and now need to do a small task in an iphone application. Basically this iphone application is a image editing applicaton. When a user click on share button in iphone a dialog is open where all there campatible application with that he can share this image like facebook, twitter, message, gmail, or more installed application is listed there.

Now my question is that how can show Myapplication in that dialog and when user select myappliation how can handel that in myapplication.

Any suggestion or Idea is highly appreciated...

This image can show you better that what is my requirement.
[image]

[image]

**Update:-**

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                    <string>CloseNormal.png</string>
                    <string>CloseSelected.png</string>
            </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Images File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
                <string>public.disk-image</string>
        <string>public.image</string>
        <string>public.fax</string>
        <string>public.jpeg</string>
        <string>public.jpeg-2000</string>
        <string>public.tiff</string>
        <string>public.camera-raw-image</string>
        <string>com.apple.pict</string>
        <string>com.apple.macpaint-image</string>
        <string>public.xbitmap-image</string>
        <string>com.apple.quicktime-image</string>

        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: @Maulik ya, that application is showing on clicked on some other application's share button, but not in gallery application..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialog is called `UIDocumentInteractionController` in iOS. For more details you should read [UIDocumentInteractionController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403) and also

[Registering the File Types Your App Supports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1).

> **Registering the File Types Your App Supports**
>
> If your app is capable of opening specific types of files, you should
>   register that support with the system. This allows other apps, through
>   the iOS document interaction technology, to offer the user the option
>   to hand off those files to your app.
>
> To declare its support for file types, your app must include the
>   CFBundleDocumentTypes key in its Info.plistproperty list file.The system adds this information to a
>   registry that other apps can access through a document interaction
>   controller.
>
> The CFBundleDocumentTypes key contains an array of dictionaries, each
>   of which identifies information about a specific document type. A
>   document type usually has a one-to-one correspondence with a
>   particular file type. However, if your app treats more than one file
>   type the same way, you can group those file types together to be
>   treated by your app as a single document type. For example, if you
>   have an old and new file format for your application’s native document
>   type, you could group both together in a single document type entry.
>   This way, old and new files would appear to be the same document type
>   and would be treated the same way.

*`Each dictionary in the CFBundleDocumentTypes array can include the following keys:`*

- `CFBundleTypeName` specifies the name of the document type.
- `CFBundleTypeIconFiles` is an array of filenames for the image
  resources to use as the document’s icon.
- `LSItemContentTypes` contains an array of strings with the UTI types
  that represent the supported file types in this group.
- `LSHandlerRank` describes whether this application owns the document
  type or is merely able to open it.

Comment: As myapp only support image file. can i have a sample piece of code..?

Comment: I am trying for that only :)

Comment: As you suggested, i have added `CFBundleDocumentTypes` in info.plist file but it still not working.. I have updated my question please look it.

Comment: download and run : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html you can see your app in sheet but it doesn't work  with gallery !

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your app to respond to the URL scheme. Information can be found in this [tutorial](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/03/05/ios-tips-and-tricks-associate-a-file-type-with-your-app-part-2.aspx)